# amazon sdk error with ruby - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I am a ruby beginner,  In my ruby on rails application  for email sending purpose I am using a ruby program, and I have using Amazon EC2 services and amazon dynamo DB, For past some days I am having issues with email sending while checking log file it says

```
ERROR WITH MESSAGE 3ea5cb565ca1c6d9546b8d6e8ad03853
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
email-sending-service.rb:21:in `block in <main>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/aws-sdk-1.14.1/lib/aws/sqs/queue.rb:287:in `block (2 levels) in poll'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/aws-sdk-1.14.1/lib/aws/sqs/queue.rb:731:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/aws-sdk-1.14.1/lib/aws/sqs/queue.rb:731:in `block in call_message_block'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/aws-sdk-1.14.1/lib/aws/sqs/queue.rb:729:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/aws-sdk-1.14.1/lib/aws/sqs/queue.rb:729:in `call_message_block'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/aws-sdk-1.14.1/lib/aws/sqs/queue.rb:198:in `receive_message'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/aws-sdk-1.14.1/lib/aws/sqs/queue.rb:284:in `block in poll'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/aws-sdk-1.14.1/lib/aws/sqs/queue.rb:282:in `loop'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/aws-sdk-1.14.1/lib/aws/sqs/queue.rb:282:in `poll'
email-sending-service.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

The 21st line of email-sending-service.rb is

```
template = email["template"]
```

I don’t know where the error comes, whether its with my ruby program or aws-sdk gem ? how to solve it ?

Comment: `email` variable holds nil. Could you post how you've created this variable?

Comment: Sorry I am just a beginner , I cant able to understand your question could you give me some more details please?

Comment: We need line where is `email = <something here>` ideally with some context before and after it.

Comment: e = Email.new email = e.get(message.body) this the lines in email-sending-services.rb program queue.poll{|message|{}

Comment: if you need I will send the full program , but note that it was worked before some time

Comment: This is still not enough to find out what is going on there. Posting the entire rails application might be quite tricky. Could you only post your Email model?

Comment: I have added one more line in question please make note of it